# Minimize the probability of winning a game with infinite independent $U(0, 1)$ random variables

Tags: probability-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

*Note: this question has been rephrased so that the problem isn't affected by boundary issues, as suggested by [mathworker21's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3293615/minimize-the-probability-of-winning-a-game-with-n-independent-u0-1-random#comment6780672_3293615). See below for the original question.*

Let $k \in [0, 1]$ be a real number.

The game starts with a random choice of a sequence $X_1, X_2, \dotsc$ of real numbers in $[0, 1]$, which are not revealed to you. At any point in the game, you can either *stop* or *show* the next number of the sequence. The goal is to stop exactly before the sum of the shown numbers exceeds $k$.

For instance, at the beginning you can do either of the following:

1. *Stop* without showing any number. If $X_1 \le k$, you lose. If $X_1 > k$, you win.
2. *Show* $X_1$. If $X_1 > k$, you lose. If $X_1 \le k$, the game goes on, and you can do either of the following:

   1. *Stop*. If $X_1 + X_2 \le k$, you lose. If $X_1 + X_2 > k$, you win.
   2. *Show* $X_2$. If $X_1 + X_2 > k$, you lose. If $X_1 + X_2 \le k$, the game goes on.

For a given $k \in [0, 1]$, any strategy will have a certain probability $p$ of winning on any given sequence. For example, if $k = 0$, the best strategy has probability $p = 1$ of winning, because you win by stopping right away.

The question is:

> Which $k$ minimizes the probability $p$ of winning?

---

In the original statement of the problem, there were only a finite number $n$ of random numbers.

For example, for $n = 2$, by showing $X_2$ you would have immediately won if $X_1 + X_2 \le k$, and lost otherwise. In that case, the probability of winning appears to be minimum if $k = \frac {\sqrt {10}} 2 - 1$, which I found by case analysis.

For $n \ge 3$, it seems unlikely that there is a simple expression of $k$ in terms of $n$.

Comment: What happens when the $n^{\text{th}}$ number comes?

Comment: If you show $X_n$, then if $X_1 + X_2 + \dotsb + X_n > k$ you lose, otherwise you win. Of course, if you can show $X_n$, it means that $X_1 + X_2 + \dotsb + X_{n-1} \le k$.

Comment: Why do you find this question interesting? I mean, there is some $k$ corresponding to the minimum probability for $n=\infty$, and for any particular $n$, the only reason that $k$ might yield a higher probability than another (close by) $k$ is because of "boundary issues", i.e. that there is a final round.

Comment: Suppose you play the game with $n+1$ numbers and threshold $k$. If you choose to show $X_1 = x$ and $x \le k$ holds, the probability of winning is the same as the probability of winning the game with $n$ variables and threshold $k - x$. For $n = \infty$, we can't use this reasoning to reduce the problem to an *easier* one, so I was under the impression that it would be harder to solve.

Comment: Of course you can! You just keep $n=\infty$ and change $k$ to $k-x$. The "base case" is just that $k \le \frac{1}{2}$ means you should stop right away.

Comment: I've tried what you suggest, but I'm stuck on some details. Anyway, now I see that you're right, the problem with $n = \infty$ is the one worth solving. If no one comes up with an answer, I'll rephrase my question according to your remark. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is my own attempt at solving the problem after mathworker21's suggestions.

Let $P(k)$ be the probability of winning the game with threshold $k$ using the best strategy.

Notice that if $0 \le k \le \frac 1 2$, by stopping right away we have probability $p = 1 - k \ge \frac 1 2$ of winning and probability $q = k \le \frac 1 2$ of losing, so we should stop right away.

In fact, there must be some $\alpha \ge \frac 1 2$ such that the best strategy will stop right away if $0 \le k \le \alpha$ for some $\alpha$, and show $X_1$ otherwise.

If $0 \le k \le \alpha$, the probability of winning is $p = 1 - k$.

If $\alpha < k \le 1$, we show $X_1 = x$. Then:

1. If $0 \le x \le k$, we haven't lost yet, and we continue the game with threshold $k - x$. Therefore we win with probability $p = P(k - x)$.
2. If $k < x \le 1$, we have lost, so we win with probability $p = 0$.

Thus the probability of winning is:
$$p = \int_0^k P(k - x) \, dx + \int_k^1 0 \, dx = \int_0^k P(x) \, dx$$

Therefore we can write:
$$P(k) = \begin{cases} 1 - k & \text{if } 0 \le k \le \alpha \\ \int_0^k P(x) \, dx & \text{if } \alpha < k \le 1 \end{cases}$$

Since $P$ must be continuous in $\alpha$, we must have $1 - \alpha = \int_0^\alpha P(x) \, dx$. The integral is:
$$\int_0^\alpha P(x) \, dx = \int_0^\alpha (1 - x) \, dx = -\frac {\alpha^2} 2 + \alpha$$
Therefore $1 - \alpha = -\frac {\alpha^2} 2 + \alpha$, which implies $\alpha = 2 - \sqrt 2$.

Now, if $\alpha < k < 1$, then $P'(k) = P(k)$, so $P(k) = c e^k$ for some $c \in \mathbb R$. Again, since $P$ is continuous in $\alpha$, we have that $1 - \alpha = c e^\alpha$, which implies $c = (1 - \alpha) e^{-\alpha}$.

Finally, we can write:
$$P(k) = \begin{cases} 1 - k & \text{if } 0 \le k \le \alpha \\ (1 - \alpha) e^{k - \alpha} & \text{if } \alpha < k \le 1 \end{cases}$$
As expected, $P$ is decreasing in $[0, \alpha]$ and increasing in $[\alpha, 1]$.

Thus the probability of winning is minimized for $k = \alpha = 2 - \sqrt 2 \approx 0.586$.